# Solr subquery highlighting

Tags: solr

Is it possible to highlight the results from a Solr subquery? For my purposes, it wouldn't matter if the highlighted values were either in the main `highlighting` section of the `response`, or split across each individual subquery.

**Updated:** The query I am working with is:

```
?q=is_pcdm:true AND {!graph from=id to=extracted_text_source}extracted_text:washington
    &fl=*,annotations:[subquery]
    &annotations.fq={!term f=extracted_text_source v=$row.id}
    &annotations.q=extracted_text:washington
    &annotations.fl=*
    &facet.field=component_not_tokenized
    &facet=on
    &wt=json
```

I want to highlight all the occurances of "washington" (my search term) in the `extracted_text` field of the documents returned by the `annotations` subquery.

Comment: could you show the example of your query?

Comment: @Mysterion updated my question with the query I've been working on

Comment: Hi, @PeterEichman did you find solution?